# Weird output when passing char[] to another function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

i'm trying to pass a char[] to another function, but for some reason I keep getting weird outputs but have no errors. I have the following methods:

```
void storeKey()
{
    char keyArray[10];
    cout << "Please enter 10bit key" << endl << "==> ";
    cin >> keyArray;
    storePlaintext(keyArray);
    cout << keyArray << endl;
}

void storePlaintext(char key[])
{
    char plaintextArray[8];    
    cout << "Please enter 8bit plaintext" << endl << "==> ";
    cin >> plaintextArray;

    cout << plaintextArray << endl << key[1] << endl;
    //cout << plaintextArray << endl << key << endl;
}
```

I should get a print out of: 00000000 and 1111111111 on the next line followed by 1111111111
But I get 0000000 then "c" (or something random) followed by 111111111. WHY is this happening? I should be able to pass a array like i'm doing with no problem right? I need to be able to pass arrays from function to function and use the data inside them. ANY help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If the array is 10 characters long then you can't store more than 9 characters in it without causing undefined behavior, because you need the 10th spot for the null terminator.  So outputting `1111111111` would indicate that you have triggered UB by entering a string longer than the program can handle in a defined way.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Buffer overflows are a problem that `std::string` all but solves.

Comment: Even if you didn't use std::string, never declare arrays that are so close to the size you want, you have no margin for error.  If you had declared those arrays with 50 characters, you wouldn't have run into the problem (but still, use `std::string` and all of those issues go away).

Comment: So if i change the 10 to an 11 it should fix the problem?

Comment: @Cris Theoretically. Is there a reason you are avoiding `std::string`? It will allocate enough memory for the input string automatically.

Comment: @Cris - Did you read my post?  Why are you declaring the arrays so close in size to what the max is?  Why not make it an array of 50 for now, and then learn std::string as soon as possible?

Comment: Or are you saying to use a string array instead? Will I be able to store each bit in an array if I use a std::string like you recommend? Also if you have time and don't mind can you provide an example using my code? It would help a ton!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry I did read it, but it didn't show until after I posted the next comment. Thanks for the tip, I was just trying to be memory efficient, I wasn't aware it would break like it did. Thanks again

Comment: It all makes sense now, thanks. simply using  string fixes all the problems. I really appreciate the help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::string`.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void storePlaintext(const string& key);

void storeKey()
{
    std::string keyArray;
    cout << "Please enter 10bit key" << endl << "==> ";
    getline(cin,  keyArray);
    storePlaintext(keyArray);
    cout << keyArray << endl;
}

void storePlaintext(const string& key)
{
    string plaintextArray;    
    cout << "Please enter 8bit plaintext" << endl << "==> ";
    getline(cin, plaintextArray);
    if ( key.size() > 1 ) 
        cout << plaintextArray << endl << key[1] << endl;
}
```

Note the use of `std::string`, `std::getline`, and passing parameters by (const) reference.  Also, the check to ensure that the `key` has more than 1 character is done, since accessing `key[1]` with a string of length 1 or less is undefined behavior.